# How can I force a cmd.exe prompt error message to not close?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

An .exe which is runs via cmd.exe runs and then quickly disappears before I can read the error message. How can I get the cmd.exe  window and error message to not close? Or is there anyway to log that error info that just flashed? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Normally when I have to do this I create a bat file in the same folder (so new text file rename to whatever.bat) open in text folder then type:

```
ProgramName.exe
Pause
```

Close and save then run the bat file and it should keep it open!

Comment: Can you add some instructions on how to do this? An average user that knows how to make a .bat file would also know how to pause at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Starting a program that launches console will indeed close the window, because CMD is no longer needed.

If you press `start` and type `cmd` and press enter, you will launch a command prompt.

Press the driveletter the program is on if this is not on C:, followed by a : and press enter.

*In the below examples the _ at the end represents your cursor.*

Example:

```
C:\Users\User>D:_

D:\>_
```

now, use the command `cd` to navigate to the directory of the program. You can press <kbd>tab</kbd> to autocomplete names. Too<kbd>tab</kbd> would make Tools if that folder exists.

Example:

```
D:\>cd Tools_

D:\Tools>cd "My Program"_   <- type 'My' and press tab to Autocomplete to "My Program"

D:\Tools\My Program>_
```

Now enter the name of the program you want to run.

Example:

```
D:\Tools\My Program>program_
Hello, I am the error message you want to see.

D:\Tools\My Program>_
```

Comment: you can use the /D switch to switch drive letters with cd so `cd /D C:\Tools` will always go to the directory no matter where you are currently

Comment: I am aware, but I wanted to keep the post as simple as possible.

Comment: Easier way : open the explorer, navigate to the directory and call "cmd" from the address bar.

Comment: @Lyrkan This is not an easier way, because it will only work if software is installed that adds this feature. 99 out of 100 times it isn't.

Comment: @LPChip It's a default feature of Windows 7/8 that works without any additional software. If you already opened the right path in the terminal there is an even more convenient way though: _Shift + Right Click_ -> _Open command window here_

Comment: Or even easier, open the command prompt, and drag and drop the program into it - Windows will insert the full path to the executable into the command prompt. Then just hit enter.

Comment: @kapep it seems you have to shift-right click on the folder, not the addressebar. But that is indeed an easier option. Alternatively, it seems to also be possible to shift-right click on an empty space in the current folder to open that folder.

Comment: @LPChip oops, yes you are right, I forgot to mention that. Yet another way on windows 8 that will open cmd at the current folder: In the explorer click _File_ -> _Open command prompt_ - there is also an option to open it as administrator.

Comment: You should consider explicitly saying that the `_` is a representation of the user's blinking cursor, lest someone tries to type the command in verbatim.

Comment: Good point schism. Will do that. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use .bat file to run that exe.

Also, you can use the following command in cmd to log the error/output of that exe file into a text file:

myFile.exe >> "C:\logFile.txt"

Double greater than symbol appends to the existing file " >> "
however, single symbol overwrite the existing file ">".

Hope this will help you to log the error.

Comment: Actually, many programs print to stderr. `>>` will only log stdout. You need to add a `2>&1`, e.g. `command 2>&1 >>log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in an already-existing instance of cmd.exe. You can press and hold shift and right-click in a directory then click "Open command window here". Then either type the name of an exe or click and drag it into the command window, then press enter.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

> || [...]  command1 || command2 Use to run the command following ||
>   only if the command preceding || fails. Cmd.exe runs the first
>   command, and then runs the second command only if the first command
>   did not complete successfully (receives an error code greater than
>   zero).

and if you are making that .exe, you just need to put `pause` command after your sentences.

And example in c++ that call the bash:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("cd  akfhaskfn|| pause");
    system("cd  || pause");

    return 0;
}
```

You will see that only the first one will call the pause command.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

just a simple version of LPChip answer (works on windows 7)
Press start and type `cmd` and press `enter`, you will launch a command prompt.
Just drag and drop what you need to run (your python script or .exe) into the cmd windows, and press `enter`. (If you need to run the cmd as admin, find the cmd in the start menu, right click on it, choose `run as admin`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert tihs

```
taskkill -im cmd.exe
```